# Chaining Nested Yields

Tags: python, yield

I want to build a data pipeline that performs a series of operations on rows of a data series.

Most functions will work on a one-row-in, one-row-out basis, but some of those operations will "expand" the series - by which I mean one row will go into the function and more than one row may be generated as a result of that function.

I want to setup a chain of functions that are robust enough to handle this behavior themselves without having to write a bunch of oversight code.

Using `yield` occurred as presenting an opportunity - if each function consumed a yield from a previous function, and acted as a generator themselves, then I can arbitrarily chain together a bunch of these well-formed functions - which would be nice from an elegance point of view.

Here's my setup code with `func_x` acting as a simple 1-1 function, and `func_y` doing an expansion.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data_source = [ OrderedDict({"id" : "1", "name" : "Tom", "sync" : "a"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "2", "name" : "Steve", "sync" : "a"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "3", "name" : "Ulrich", "sync" : "b"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "4", "name" : "Victor", "sync" : "b"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "5", "name" : "Wolfgang", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "6", "name" : "Xavier", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "7", "name" : "Yves", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "8", "name" : "Zaphod", "sync" : "d"})]
def row_getter(source):
    for content in source:
        yield content.copy()

def func_x(row):
    try:
        q=next(row)
        if q['name']=="Tom":
            q['name']="Richard"
        yield q.copy()
    except StopIteration:
        print ("Stop x")


def func_y(row):
    try:
        q=next(row)
        for thingy in range(0,2):
            q['thingy']=thingy
            yield q.copy()
    except StopIteration:
        print ("Stop y")

rg = row_getter(data_source)
iter_func = func_y(func_x(rg))
```

Now, I can get the first set of data by iterating through the iter_func object:

```
print (next(iter_func))
>> OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'Richard'), ('sync', 'a'), ('thingy', 0)])
```

And again:

```
print (next(iter_func))
>> OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'Richard'), ('sync', 'a'), ('thingy', 1)])
```

And again, though this time, instead of seeing the record for Steve (i.e. the next record in the flow, now the expansion of func_y on the first record is complete) I get a `StopIteration` error.

```
print (next(iter_func))
>> StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0fd1ed48c61b> in <module>()
----> 1 print (next(iter_func))

StopIteration:
```

So I don't understand where this is coming from, since I've attempted to trap these in both `func_x` and `func_y`.

Comment: You don't need `rowgetter`; it basically just reimplements `iter`.

Comment: Is it intentional that `func_x` and `func_y` will modify the contents of `data_source`?

Comment: No, it's not - loosely speaking, the starting data is disposable - I don't refer to it other than by reading it into the start of the pipeline, but I ought to clean that up before it generates any unwanted side-effects. \[edited\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `func_x` function only yields one item, so it finalizes after that one is consumed. Try with something like this:

```
def func_x(row):
    try:
        for q in row:
            if q['name']=="Tom":
                q['name']="Richard"
            yield q
    except StopIteration:
        print ("Stop x")
```

By the way, note that each yielding does **not** make a copy of the object. This may be fine in many cases, but note that in `func_y` you are yielding each same object twice, setting `'thingy'` to a different value. This means that if for example you do (after the code you posted):

```
d1 = next(iter_func)
d2 = next(iter_func)
```

`d1` and `d2` will be the same object, and in particular they will both have `'thingy'` set to `1`.

Comment: Ahh yes, so I need to make sure each function follows that `for q in row:` pattern, yes! Makes sense - and also, yeah on the copy/overwrite behaviour, I need to remember to avoid causing myself problems due to that.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in tools (specifically `map` and `itertools.chain`) can do this for you.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain


data_source = [ OrderedDict({"id" : "1", "name" : "Tom", "sync" : "a"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "2", "name" : "Steve", "sync" : "a"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "3", "name" : "Ulrich", "sync" : "b"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "4", "name" : "Victor", "sync" : "b"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "5", "name" : "Wolfgang", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "6", "name" : "Xavier", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "7", "name" : "Yves", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "8", "name" : "Zaphod", "sync" : "d"})]


def rename(d):
    if d['name'] == "Tom":
        d['name'] = "Richard"
    return d


def add_thingy(d):
    for y in range(2):
        yield {'thingy': y, **d}

for x in chain.from_iterable(add_thingy(d) 
                             for d in map(rename,
                                          data_source)):
    print(x)
```

`map` isn't really necessary; we can apply  `rename` to each `dict` before we pass it to `add_thingy` in the generator expression.

```
for x in chain.from_iterable(add_thingy(rename(d)) for d in data_source):
    print(x)
```

or go the other way and use `map` twice:

```
for x in chain.from_iterable(map(add_thingy, map(rename, data_source))):
    print(x)
```